# Undesirable Query String in MVC after post data

Tags: ajax, query-string, asp.net-mvc-5

i have this script to fill my modalbox's with ajax in MVC5 & this script make this query string in the first :

```
function Edit(elem) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Service/Edit",
            type: "get",
            data: { 'id': elem },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#bodyEditmodal").html(result);
                $('#myModalEditLabel').html('ویرایش سرویس');
            }
        });
```

http://homeservice.microcloud.ir/***panel2***/Service/Edit/2

but when post back is happening my query string is change to

http://homeservice.microcloud.ir/Service/Edit/2

whats problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not aware that the two dots at beginning of `../Service/Edit` makes the url go one folder up, removing the /panel2 from the path.

try this:

```
function Edit (elem) {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        url: "Service/Edit",
        type: "get",
        data: { 'id': elem },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#bodyEditmodal").html(result)
            $('#myModalEditLabel').html('ویرایش سرویس')
        }
    })
}
```

or better yet specify the complete url:

```
function Edit (elem) {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        url: "/panel2/Service/Edit",
        type: "get",
        data: { 'id': elem },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#bodyEditmodal").html(result)
            $('#myModalEditLabel').html('ویرایش سرویس')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin , My installation address is : Panel2
 this is for test it in my internal server

Comment: for the first time yep ! but when post back is happening no & query string is changing ! i use this type of addressing usually

Comment: Do you get any response? You can check if the url is working in browser, something like `localhost:3000/panel2/Service/Edit`

Comment: thanks a lot ! i resolved this problem with following addressing :   url: "@Url.Action("Edit", "Service")", instead of url: "../Service/Edit",